# What is the meaning of this typedef struct in C language?

Tags: c, struct, typedef

What is the meaning of this code?

```
typedef struct elmt *elmtaddress;
```

Comment: did you search a little ?

Comment: Before asking a question, search it on Google **#mangoogle**

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: It means that neither you nor the person who wrote the code has paid attention to [Is it a good idea to typedef pointers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers)

Comment: I'm sorry for my bad question.. This is my first time asking in stackoverflow.. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes `elmtadress` an alias for `struct elmt *`. If you use this, you can type:

```
elmtadress myStruct;
```

instead of

```
struct slmt *myStruct;
```

Read more here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_typedef.htm

Comment: thanks, and sorry for my bad question and thanks for the edit..